# How do I undo "replace"?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I didn't realize that "replace" meant the log messages from the previous file will be gone, now the log messages start with when I replaced the file and so on.

I need a way to revert it back to the previous file (before I replaced it). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you've deleted the old file, so the advice on [Resurrecting Deleted Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect) will link the log trail back to where it was before your replace.

You could then apply the differences between the old and new files in-place, instead of either deleting the old file and adding a new one or copying another file on top, however you "replace"d the file the first time, to preserve history.

Of course, whether the discontinuity in the log is a problem is really a matter of judgment.  You could simply note in the log for a new revision which old revision in which to find the previous file of that name.